# Uploading a CSV file to s3 From Apex

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, apex

I need to upload a CSV file from Apex to a global bucket in s3 and keep the URL.

Below described is my approach for the same using AWS request signing process.

```
 public static void uploadCSVFileToS3(String csvFile, String filename, String awsAccessKey, String awsSecretKey, String bucketname){
    try{
        String formattedDateString = Datetime.now().format('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');
        String requestType = 'PUT';
        String contentType = 'text/csv';
        String filePath = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' + '/'+ bucketname + '/' + 'demo.csv';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod(requestType);
        req.setHeader('Host','https://s3.amazonaws.com');
        req.setEndpoint(filePath);
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(csvFile.length()));
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
        req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read-write');
        Blob CSV = Blob.valueof(csvFile);
        req.setBodyAsBlob(CSV);

        String auth = createAuthHeader(requestType, contentType, filename, formattedDateString, bucketname, awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

        Http http = new Http();

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('RESPONSE STRING: ' + res.toString());
        System.debug('RESPONSE STATUS: ' + res.getStatus());
        System.debug('STATUS_CODE: ' + res.getStatusCode());
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        system.debug('AWS Service Callout Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        system.debug('AWS Service Callout Exception: ' + e.getCause());
        system.debug('Exception: ' + e.getStackTraceString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        system.debug('Exception: ' + e.getStackTraceString());
    }  
}

public static String createAuthHeader(String method, String contentType, String filename, String formattedDateString, String bucket, String key, String secret){
    string auth;

    String stringToSign = method+'\n'+bucket+'/'+filename+'\n';
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', blob.valueof(stringToSign), blob.valueof(secret));
    String sig = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
    auth = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + sig;


    return auth;
}
```

I have followed the link here (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BMDFIA4) for the approach used.

I am able to upload the file to the same bucket from ruby or javascript using the AWS SDK's, but it is giving me a response code of 400 (Bad Request).
I think this is a problem of the process of signing request.

It will be highly appreciated if someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f) which describes the authentication process for AWS clearly.

http://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f